# Get with mysql the same result/aim as with php

Tags: mysql

Excuse me for long post.

I have such php code.

```
    ['date' => '2023-03-03', 'quantity' => 5, 'price' => 9],
    ['date' => '2023-04-01', 'quantity' => 2, 'price' => 10],
    ['date' => '2023-04-04', 'quantity' => 6, 'price' => 15],
];

$sales = [
    ['date' => '2023-03-04', 'quantity' => 2],
    ['date' => '2023-04-02', 'quantity' => 1],
    ['date' => '2023-04-05', 'quantity' => 5],
    ['date' => '2023-04-06', 'quantity' => 3],
];

$sales_for_update = [];

foreach ($sales as $sales_row) {
foreach ($purchases as $key => $purchase) {
if ($sales_row['quantity'] > 0 && $sales_row['quantity'] <= $purchase['quantity']) {
$sales_for_update[] = [
'date' => $sales_row['date'],
'quantity' => $sales_row['quantity'],
'purchase_price' => $purchase['price'],
];
$purchases[$key]['quantity'] -= $sales_row['quantity'];
break;
} 
elseif ($sales_row['quantity'] > 0 && $sales_row['quantity'] > $purchase['quantity']) {
$sales_for_update[] = [
'date' => $sales_row['date'],
'quantity' => $purchase['quantity'],
'purchase_price' => $purchase['price'],
];
$sales_row['quantity'] -= $purchase['quantity'];
unset($purchases[$key]);
}
}
} 

echo '<pre>', print_r($sales_for_update, true), '</pre>';
```

And i get exactly what i need. Need following.

Loop through each sales row and, within that loop, iterate over the purchases rows.

Compare the sold quantity with the purchased quantity and update the sales and purchases data accordingly.

If the sold quantity is less than or equal to the purchased quantity, code writes the sold quantity and purchase price to the $sales_for_update array, updates the purchased quantity, and moves to the next sales row.

If the sold quantity is greater than the purchased quantity, code writes the purchased quantity and purchase price to the $sales_for_update array, removes the used purchased quantity, and moves to the next purchases row.

Trying to get the same with mysql.

Create tables and insert the same data as in php arrays.

```
$db->exec("
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 0purchases (
        Date DATE,
        Quantity INT,
        Price DECIMAL(10, 2)
    )
");

// Insert data into the Purchases table
$purchases = [
    ['2023-03-03', 5, 9],
    ['2023-04-01', 2, 10],
    ['2023-04-04', 6, 15]
];

$insertPurchases = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO 0purchases (Date, Quantity, Price) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");

foreach ($purchases as $purchase) {
    $insertPurchases->execute($purchase);
}

// Create the Sales table
$db->exec("
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 0sales (
        Date DATE,
        Quantity INT
    )
");

// Insert data into the Sales table
$sales = [
    ['2023-03-04', 2],
    ['2023-04-02', 1],
    ['2023-04-05', 5],
    ['2023-04-06', 3]
];

$insertSales = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO 0sales (Date, Quantity) VALUES (?, ?)");

foreach ($sales as $sale) {
    $insertSales->execute($sale);
}
```

And now trying multiple variations of mysql code and none of them gives correct results. Tried

```
SELECT
    s.date,
    s.quantity AS sold_quantity,
    p.quantity AS purchased_quantity,
    p.price AS purchase_price
FROM
    0sales s
JOIN
    0purchases p ON p.date <= s.date
GROUP BY
    s.date, s.quantity, p.date, p.quantity, p.price
HAVING
    s.quantity <= p.quantity
ORDER BY
    s.date
```

```
SELECT  
    s.date,
s.quantity AS sold_quantity,
    p.quantity AS purchased_quantity,
    p.price AS purchase_price
FROM
    0sales s
JOIN
    0purchases p ON p.date <= s.date

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        s.date,
        SUM(s.quantity) AS sold_quantity,
        SUM(p.quantity) AS purchased_quantity
    FROM
        0sales s
    JOIN
        0purchases p ON p.date <= s.date
GROUP BY s.date 
-- GROUP BY s.quantity
) AS t ON t.date = s.date
WHERE
    s.quantity <= (purchased_quantity - COALESCE(sold_quantity, 0))
-- ORDER BY s.date
-- GROUP BY s.quantity 
GROUP BY s.date, s.quantity, p.quantity, p.price
```

and many other variations and can not get correct results. Need the same as with php code...